# Why is Firestore array-contains not working?

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I have a very basic query i am running in both my app using react native and in the firestore webconsole and neither of them is returning results. Is my data incorrect or is my query? I have an array of ids as an attribute and want to find all documents that have a value of 114 inside of the array.

My react native app is running on ios 14.4 and running "@react-native-firebase/storage": "^11.0.0",.

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import {Button} from 'material-bread';

import firestore from '@react-native-firebase/firestore';
import {uuidv4} from '../../utils/uuid';

const TestPage = () => {
  return (
    <View style={{paddingTop: 140}}>
      <Button
        text={'Add test data record'}
        type="flat"
        textColor={'#FFFFFF'}
        color={`#000000`}
        fullWidth
        onPress={() => {
          firestore()
            .collection('Testing')
            .doc(uuidv4())
            .set({
              exercise_ids: [
                112,
                114,
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
                Math.random(),
              ],
            })
            .then(() => {})
            .catch((err) => {
              console.log(err);
            });
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default TestPage;
```

query

```
.where("exercise_ids", "array-contains", 114)
```

data

```
{exercise_ids: [114,25]}
```

[image: Picture of query]

[image: Picture of data]

Video of the issue https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMS4P32BX9dPirhLJIm2qDzx0_XBxdPb/view?usp=drive_web

Comment: Please edit your question to show the complete query, and how you read/process the data, instead of merely the `where` clause that you think it causing the problem. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), for more advice that maximizes the chance that someone can help.

Comment: I have reproduced your issue and I am able to see that "array-contains" works successfully. However in your first screenshot, I am not able to see that you have any documents in the collection "lift_tracker_groups" and you are trying the filter with "array-contains". In the second screenshot, I Can see that you have documents  but there I can't see that you are trying to filter and not getting documents. Please provide more information of what is exactly not working.

Comment: So i have dug in further and found out my issue is related react native create numbers inside of the array. Here is a link to a video i made showcasing the issue https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nMS4P32BX9dPirhLJIm2qDzx0_XBxdPb/view?usp=drive_web . I'll update this page with my react component and firestore version number.

Comment: The mystery thickens, if you create an array of numbers with the react native code you can query the data in the react native code but not in the web console. If you create an array of numbers with the web console you can't query them with the react native code. If you update data you created with the react native code with the web console you can no longer query it with react native either.

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced your scenario and I did some tests when querying for a specific document:

```
"test_array": {
          "arrayValue": {
            "values": [
              {
                "integerValue": "1"
              },
              {
                "integerValue": "2"
              },
              {
                "doubleValue": 0.001
              },
              {
                "integerValue": "3"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
```

So according to the document format shown up, these are all **numbers** but in reality the data types are **ints / doubles**.

So your **React Native** Application is uploading the numbers of type double. That's why as a result, the query (which is interpreted as an int) does't match the double value.

In other words the value 2 (int) != 2 (double) when querying.

Note this issue is specific to web as JS doesn't differential between the two datatypes. They're both numbers. So the implicit casting in the web sdk / console can yield unexpected results.

I have found this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3004) which is opened, please comment their regarding your issue as it seems to be a React Native issue.

Or otherwise you can create a [bug Report](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/3004) to the Firebase Support Team.